# Complex Analysis - finding the pole

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I find the order of the pole of $$\frac{\sin(x^2)}{(x-7)^9(x^5+x+1)^3}$$ at $x = 7$?

Comment: The _order_ of the pole, perhaps?  Or maybe the residue of the pole?  You've already found the pole itself (at $z=7$).

Comment: The question asking me the order of pole, so is the answer is just as simple as 7? what if the question asking for x=1?

Comment: Why $z$ when your function is $x$?

Comment: What is the definition of the order of a pole?  Start with simpler questions: what is the order of the pole at $x=7$ of $f(x)=1$?  Of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-7}$?  Of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-7)^2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that for

$$f(z)=\frac{\sin(z^2)}{(z-7)^9(z^5+z+1)^3}$$

$(z-7)^9f(z)$ is bounded near $z=7$, but $(z-7)^8f(z)$ is not bounded near $z=7$.

So $f(z)$ has a pole of order $9$ at $z=7$.

Note that $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=1$, precisely because $z=1$ is not a root of the denominator of $f(z)$.